# Appending all hyperlinks with a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of pages on a website that may or may not contain links pointing to xyz.com.

When a page is loading, I have to determine if the hyperlink on the page contains a link to xyz.com (it can be something.xyz.com or anything.xyz.com).

Once found, I have to append a string ?BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-1938 to the end of it.

So a hyperlink like `https://something.xyz.com/blog/category/` will become `https://something.xyz.com/blog/category/?BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-1938`

How can I do it? This is what I have come up so far.

```
var matchingElements = $("a[href*='/xyz.com/']")

var hrefs = matchingElements.map(function(index, element) {
    return $(element).attr('href');
});

$.each(matchingElements, function(index, val) { 
    $(this).attr('href', function(){ 
        return this.href + '?BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-1938';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way is to set the `search` property of each of the links.

`<a>` elements have similar properties as `window.location` such as search, host, pathname etc as well as href.

```js
$("a[href*='example.com']").prop('search', 'BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-1938')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/foo/bar">Link 1</a>
<a href="https://anything.example.com/bar/foo">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: This is brilliant and concise. Is there a way I can set it for multiple urls. For eg: if url is something.example.com, then append BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-1938 else for everything other than something.example.com (eg: xxxx.example.com) append BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-200

Comment: Check this example out https://jsfiddle.net/cLk1bpd6/

Comment: Spot on! Thanks for your expertise.

Comment: I tested it on a few urls. If my original url has a "?" in it, the code behaves erratically. For eg: "example.com/blog/details.aspx?id=53" should become "example.com/blog/details.aspx?id=53&BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-1938" but it doesn't. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: More robust version using [URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)  ... https://jsfiddle.net/0ktp2u5L/

Comment: This works so good. I am trying to learn too and let's say for example that the two strings were AMX-DO-1938 and XO-DO-200, how would I change the code to make it work with urls with "?"

Comment: Look at the href of the two links in the last demo. They both have search params `?x=1&foo=bar` hard coded in them already....before modifying with the new param. Using the `append()` method of URLSearchParams adds to existing

Comment: You are correct. I think the single quote .`${doNum}` is causing issues on my site as it throws an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. On JSFiddle it works fine.

 How is ` different from ' ?

Comment: It's *template literal* syntax. relatively new and may not be supported in your environment. Can use old fashioned string concatention instead. I just put it together quickly for demo purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your solution like this,

```
$("a[href*='/xyz.com/']")
       .each(function()
       { 
          this.href = this.href + '?BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-1938';
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `each` and `attr`

```js
$("a[href*='xyz.com']").each(function () {
  $(this).attr(
    "href",
    $(this).attr("href") +
      ($(this).attr("href").includes("something.xyz.com")
        ? "?BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-1938"
        : "?BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-200")
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a target="_blank" href="https://something.xyz.com/blog/category/">Link 1</a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://something.xyz.com/blog/post/">Link 2</a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://something.abc.com/blog/post/">Link 3</a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://otherthing.xyz.com/blog/post/">Link 4</a>
```

Comment: This solution too will come in very handy. I am reposting my comment here. Is there a way I can set it for multiple urls. For eg: if url is something.example.com, then append BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-1938 else for everything other than something.example.com (eg: xxxx.example.com) append BX.ref_id=AMX-DO-200

Comment: @CuriousDev udpated answer. you could use ternary operator and `includes` to check if the current `href` is like `something.xyz.com`

Comment: Fantastic. Now I know how to do this in two ways. Thanks @hgb123, Upvoted!